# Genetic algorithm resource

Tags: algorithm, resources, genetic-algorithm

Lately I'm interested in the topic of genetic algorithms, but I couldn't find any good resource. If you know any good resource, book or a site I would appreciate it. I have solid knowledge of algorithms and Artificial Intelligence but I'm looking for something with good introduction in Genetic Programming.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for genetic algorithms, or genetic programming?

Comment: GP != GA != Hill Climbing with mutation

Comment: Please also, consider [openGA](https://github.com/Arash-codedev/openGA).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Best references for me so far:

- [Genetic Algorithms in Search,
  Optimization, and Machine
  Learning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201157675) by David E. Goldberg: a
  classic, still considered as the
  bible of GAs by many.
- [An Introduction to Genetic
  Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262631857) by Melanie Mitchell:
  more recent than the previous reference and packed with
  probably more interesting examples.
- [A Field Guide to Genetic Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1409200736) by Poli, Langdon, McPhee: this is more of a hands on guide and is getting very good reviews.

Also if you're an absolute beginner I'd suggest you to start with the [Hello World of Genetics Algorithms](http://www.generation5.org/content/2003/gahelloworld.asp). There's nothing like a nice clean example to get started.

Comment: I should say, An Introduction to Genetic Algorithms by Melanie Mitchell is a good bet. I read Melane Mitchell's "Complexity: A Guided Tour" for Complex Systems Theory -- and I can't imagine a better job done at writing technical material.

Comment: @Cody yeah Complexity is very good, I like it a lot too :)

Answer (score 15):

I found Melanie Mitchell's book, [An Introduction to Genetic Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262631857), to be very good.  For a wider coverage of evolutionary computation topics, [Introduction to Evolutionary Computing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540401849) by Eiben and Smith is also worthwhile.

If you're just starting out, I recently wrote an [introductory article](http://blog.uncommons.org/2009/01/20/practical-evolutionary-computation-an-introduction/) that may be of use.

There are further links both in that article and also on the [home page](https://watchmaker.dev.java.net/) for my evolutionary computation framework.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but no answer has been accepted yet, so I thought I'd add my own contribution. One of the best free resources in my opinion for all things related to evolutionary computation (genetic algorithms, evolution strategies, genetic programming, etc.) is Sean Luke's online book [Essentials of Metaheuristics](http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/).

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice free book on the subject

http://www.lulu.com/items/volume_63/2167000/2167025/2/print/book.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Here is Roger Alsing's recent article about building "Mona Lisa's picture" with a genetic algorithm :http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/

**Edited to remove hot link to the picture** See: http://rogeralsing.files.wordpress.com/2008/12/evolutionofmonalisa1.gif

I've implemented my own version of this algorithm:

[image: http://23.media.tumblr.com/NngfN9gsDhlsyws3NvFcuHfgo1_400.png]
<sub>(source: [tumblr.com](http://23.media.tumblr.com/NngfN9gsDhlsyws3NvFcuHfgo1_400.png))</sub>

See http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2008/12/random-notes-2008-12.html

Comment: Thats a cool image sequence, I doubt the owner of that blog would like you hotlinking it though.

Comment: @Jamie. You're right. I removed the link.

Comment: The original is not even close to a genetic algorithm (haven't looked at yours though). Its simulated annealing with a greedy acceptance criteria.

Comment: Be careful what you're calling a GA!

Answer (score 3):

There is a great introduction to genetic algorithms at [AI-Junkie.com](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat1.html) as well as tutorials on many other AI and machine learning techniques. The genetic algorithms tutorial is aimed to 'explain genetic algorithms sufficiently for you to be able to use them in your own projects' while keeping the mathematics down as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

### [Clever Algorithms: Nature-Inspired Programming Recipes](http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/index.html)

#### by Jason Brownlee PhD.

This book is available [free in PDF](http://www.lulu.com/shop/jason-brownlee/clever-algorithms-nature-inspired-programming-recipes/ebook/product-17386095.html). Book covers large amount of nature-inspired algorithms, including evolutionary, swarm and neural algorithms.

[image: book cover]

Answer (score 1):

A short introduction I wrote a long time ago is available [here](http://gaul.sourceforge.net/intro.html), but a better short introduction is [here](http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/).

For a larger and comprehensive, although somewhat out-dated, list of resources visit the [comp.ai.genetic FAQ](http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~rij/gafaq/top.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If I may plug one of my favorite books, [*The Algorithm Design Manual*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600) by Steve Skiena has a great section on genetic algorithms (plus a lot of other interesting heuristics for solving various types of problems).

Answer (score 0):

The book [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://oreilly.com/catalog/978059652932) by OReilly had chapter covering genetic algorithms.
It might be a little bit to basic but it was a very illustrating example.

Answer (score 0):

[Practical Genetic Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471188735)

Answer (score 0):

'An Introduction to Genetic Algorithms' http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/genetic.html

Answer (score 0):

For an introductory approach (with an application to the Prisoner's Dilemma), see into:

http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/tesfatsi/holland.gaintro.htm

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a Genetic Algorithm with java generics. https://github.com/juanmf/ga

It will apply the 3 operators (Mutation, crossing, Selection), and evolve a population, given the concrete implementations of Individual, Gen, FitnessMeter and factories exposed as spring beans.

```
/*This is all you have to add to the Spring App context 
 * before running the application
 */
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean(name="individualFactory")
    public IndividualFactory getIndividualFactory() {
        return new Team.TeamFactory();
    }

    @Bean(name="populationFactory")
    public PopulationFactory getPopulationFactory() {
        return new Team.TeamPopulationFactory();
    }

    @Bean(name="fitnessMeter")
    public FitnessMeter getFitnessMeter() {
        System.out.println("getFitnessMeter");
        return new TeamAptitudeMeter();
    }
}
```

[image]
This is the design, inside grandt there is an implementation of a specific problem solution, as an example.